# Python GPS Module: Reading latest GPS Data

Tags: python, gps, gpsd

I have been trying to work with the standard **GPS (gps.py) module in python** 2.6. This is supposed to act as a client and read GPS Data from gpsd running in Ubuntu.

According to the documentation from GPSD webpage on client design ([GPSD Client Howto](http://gpsd.berlios.de/client-howto.html#_python_examples)), I should be able to use the following code (slightly modified from the example)  for getting latest GPS Readings (lat long is what I am mainly interested in)

```
from gps import *
session = gps() # assuming gpsd running with default options on port 2947
session.stream(WATCH_ENABLE|WATCH_NEWSTYLE)
report = session.next()
print report
```

If I repeatedly use the next() it gives me buffered values from the bottom of the queue (from when the session was started), and not the LATEST Gps reading. Is there a way to get more recent values using this library? In a Way, seek the Stream to the latest values?

Has anyone got a code example using this library to poll the gps and get the value i am looking for ?

**Here is what I am trying to do:**

1. start the session
2. Wait for user to call the gps_poll() method in my code
3. Inside this method read the latest TPV (Time Position Velocity) report and return lat long
4. Go back to waiting for user to call gps_poll()

Answer (score 19, accepted):

What you need to do is regularly poll 'session.next()' - the issue here is that you're dealing with a serial interface - you get results in the order they were received. Its up to you to maintain a 'current_value' that has the latest retrieved value.

If you don't poll the session object, eventually your UART FIFO will fill up and you won't get any new values anyway.

Consider using a thread for this, don't wait for the user to call gps_poll(), you should be polling and when the user wants a new value they use 'get_current_value()' which returns current_value.

Off the top of my head it could be something as simple as this:

```
import threading
import time
from gps import *

class GpsPoller(threading.Thread):

   def __init__(self):
       threading.Thread.__init__(self)
       self.session = gps(mode=WATCH_ENABLE)
       self.current_value = None

   def get_current_value(self):
       return self.current_value

   def run(self):
       try:
            while True:
                self.current_value = self.session.next()
                time.sleep(0.2) # tune this, you might not get values that quickly
       except StopIteration:
            pass

if __name__ == '__main__':

   gpsp = GpsPoller()
   gpsp.start()
   # gpsp now polls every .2 seconds for new data, storing it in self.current_value
   while 1:
       # In the main thread, every 5 seconds print the current value
       time.sleep(5)
       print gpsp.get_current_value()
```

Comment: The answer looks good, but the sleep(0.2) isn't required. session.next() will block, so having it in the while True loop will not overload your cpu anyway.

Comment: are `get_current_value()` and `session.next()` atomic?  You need a lock or some synchronization mechanism if not.

Comment: Reading/replacing a single instance variable is a thread safe operation automatically with Python.

Answer (score 18):

The above answers are very inefficient and overly complex for anyone using modern versions of gpsd and needing data at only specific times, instead of streaming.

Most GPSes send their position information at least once per second. Presumably since many GPS-based applications desire real-time updates, the vast majority of gpsd client examples I've seen use the above method of watching a stream from gpsd and receiving realtime updates (more or less as often as the gps sends them).

However, if (as in the OP's case) you don't *need* streaming information but just need the last-reported position whenever it's requested (i.e. via user interaction or some other event), there's a much more efficient and simpler method: let gpsd cache the latest position information, and query it when needed.

The [gpsd JSON protocol](https://gpsd.gitlab.io/gpsd/gpsd_json.html) has a `?POLL;` request, which returns the most recent GPS information that gpsd has seen. Instead of having to iterate over the backlog of gps messages, and continually read new messages to avoid full buffers, you can send a `?WATCH={"enable":true}` message at the start of the gpsd session, and then query the latest position information whenever you need it with `?POLL;`. The response is a single JSON object containing the most recent information that gpsd has seen from the GPS.

If you're using Python3, the easiest way I've found is to use the [gpsd-py3](https://github.com/MartijnBraam/gpsd-py3) package available on pypi. To connect to gpsd, get the latest position information, and print the current position:

```
import gpsd
gpsd.connect()
packet = gpsd.get_current()
print(packet.position())
```

You can repeat the `gpsd.get_current()` call whenever you want new position information, and behind the scenes the gpsd package will execute the `?POLL;` call to gpsd and return an object representing the response.

Doing this with the built-in `gps` module isn't terribly straightforward, but there are a number of other Python clients available, and it's also rather trivial to do with anything that can perform socket communication, including this example using `telnet`:

```
$ telnet localhost 2947
Trying ::1...
Connected to localhost.
Escape character is '^]'.
{"class":"VERSION","release":"3.16","rev":"3.16","proto_major":3,"proto_minor":11}
?WATCH={"enable":true}
{"class":"DEVICES","devices":[{"class":"DEVICE","path":"/dev/pts/10","driver":"SiRF","activated":"2018-03-02T21:14:52.687Z","flags":1,"native":1,"bps":4800,"parity":"N","stopbits":1,"cycle":1.00}]}
{"class":"WATCH","enable":true,"json":false,"nmea":false,"raw":0,"scaled":false,"timing":false,"split24":false,"pps":false}
?POLL;
{"class":"POLL","time":"2018-03-02T21:14:54.873Z","active":1,"tpv":[{"class":"TPV","device":"/dev/pts/10","mode":3,"time":"2005-06-09T14:34:53.280Z","ept":0.005,"lat":46.498332203,"lon":7.567403907,"alt":1343.165,"epx":24.829,"epy":25.326,"epv":78.615,"track":10.3788,"speed":0.091,"climb":-0.085,"eps":50.65,"epc":157.23}],"gst":[{"class":"GST","device":"/dev/pts/10","time":"1970-01-01T00:00:00.000Z","rms":0.000,"major":0.000,"minor":0.000,"orient":0.000,"lat":0.000,"lon":0.000,"alt":0.000}],"sky":[{"class":"SKY","device":"/dev/pts/10","time":"2005-06-09T14:34:53.280Z","xdop":1.66,"ydop":1.69,"vdop":3.42,"tdop":3.05,"hdop":2.40,"gdop":5.15,"pdop":4.16,"satellites":[{"PRN":23,"el":6,"az":84,"ss":0,"used":false},{"PRN":28,"el":7,"az":160,"ss":0,"used":false},{"PRN":8,"el":66,"az":189,"ss":45,"used":true},{"PRN":29,"el":13,"az":273,"ss":0,"used":false},{"PRN":10,"el":51,"az":304,"ss":29,"used":true},{"PRN":4,"el":15,"az":199,"ss":36,"used":true},{"PRN":2,"el":34,"az":241,"ss":41,"used":true},{"PRN":27,"el":71,"az":76,"ss":42,"used":true}]}]}
?POLL;
{"class":"POLL","time":"2018-03-02T21:14:58.856Z","active":1,"tpv":[{"class":"TPV","device":"/dev/pts/10","mode":3,"time":"2005-06-09T14:34:53.280Z","ept":0.005,"lat":46.498332203,"lon":7.567403907,"alt":1343.165,"epx":24.829,"epy":25.326,"epv":78.615,"track":10.3788,"speed":0.091,"climb":-0.085,"eps":50.65,"epc":157.23}],"gst":[{"class":"GST","device":"/dev/pts/10","time":"1970-01-01T00:00:00.000Z","rms":0.000,"major":0.000,"minor":0.000,"orient":0.000,"lat":0.000,"lon":0.000,"alt":0.000}],"sky":[{"class":"SKY","device":"/dev/pts/10","time":"2005-06-09T14:34:53.280Z","xdop":1.66,"ydop":1.69,"vdop":3.42,"tdop":3.05,"hdop":2.40,"gdop":5.15,"pdop":4.16,"satellites":[{"PRN":23,"el":6,"az":84,"ss":0,"used":false},{"PRN":28,"el":7,"az":160,"ss":0,"used":false},{"PRN":8,"el":66,"az":189,"ss":45,"used":true},{"PRN":29,"el":13,"az":273,"ss":0,"used":false},{"PRN":10,"el":51,"az":304,"ss":29,"used":true},{"PRN":4,"el":15,"az":199,"ss":36,"used":true},{"PRN":2,"el":34,"az":241,"ss":41,"used":true},{"PRN":27,"el":71,"az":76,"ss":42,"used":true}]}]}
```

Comment: This is both much easier and much better than the accepted answer.

Comment: This answer is a great explanation of gpsd usage for any client, not just Python, just by using ?WATCH={"enable":true} and ?POLL.

More info here: https://gpsd.gitlab.io/gpsd/client-howto.html

Answer (score 2):

Adding my two cents.

For whatever reason my raspberry pi would continue to execute a thread and I'd have to hard reset the pi.

So I've combined sysnthesizerpatel and an answer I found on Dan Mandel's blog [here](http://www.danmandle.com/blog/getting-gpsd-to-work-with-python/).

My gps_poller class looks like this:

```
import os 
from gps import *
from time import *
import time 
import threading 

class GpsPoller(threading.Thread):

    def __init__(self):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.session = gps(mode=WATCH_ENABLE)
        self.current_value = None 
        self.running = True 

    def get_current_value(self):
        return self.current_value

    def run(self):
        try:
            while self.running:
                self.current_value = self.session.next() 
        except StopIteration:
            pass
```

And the code in use looks like this:

```
from gps_poll import *

if __name__ == '__main__':
    gpsp = GpsPoller()
    try: 
        gpsp.start() 
        while True:
            os.system('clear')
            report = gpsp.get_current_value()
            # print report 
            try: 
                if report.keys()[0] == 'epx':
                    print report['lat']
                    print report['lon']           
                time.sleep(.5)
            except(AttributeError, KeyError):
                pass 
            time.sleep(0.5)

    except(KeyboardInterrupt, SystemExit):
        print "\nKilling Thread.."
        gpsp.running = False 
        gpsp.join()

    print "Done.\nExiting."
```

You can also find the code here: [Here](https://github.com/timmyreilly/BumpyRoads/blob/master/RaspberryPiFiles/gpsData.py) and [Here](https://github.com/timmyreilly/BumpyRoads/blob/master/RaspberryPiFiles/gps_poll.py)

Comment: Better than what I suggested!

Comment: This code is bad. `current_value` gets written every time gpsd sends data. With the `time.sleep(.5)`, the `while True` loop manages to miss the `epx` report *every* time, thus printing no GPS data at all. Note that this is very timing dependent - for some people it may *work* every time. This will be fixed if the check for `epx` is moved to the `GpsPoller` class. Even then, locking needs to be added.

Answer (score 1):

I know its an old thread but just for everyone understanding, you can also use `pyembedded` python library for this.

`pip install pyembedded`

```
from pyembedded.gps_module.gps import GPS
import time    

gps = GPS(port='COM3', baud_rate=9600)

while True:
    print(gps.get_lat_long())
    time.sleep(1)
```

https://pypi.org/project/pyembedded/