# Get different values from self.current_value for Raspberry Pi GPS poller

Tags: python, gps, raspberry-pi, gpsd

I'm trying to figure out how to make a script that will run in the background and give me the current values of latitude, longitude, altitude, etc of a gps. I would also like to have it update the speed to the maximum. I found this helpful guide
[Python GPS Module: Reading latest GPS Data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6146131/python-gps-module-reading-latest-gps-data/6146351#6146351?newreg=3c1d44fcdecd4c438dab3754836777cb)

But I don't know how to get the latitude, longitude, etc from self.current_value. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: StackOverflow expects verifiable examples. You should provide what you've attempted.

Comment: Hint: open the TTY/UART device where your GPS receiver is connected and read/parse the strings coming out. The protocol is very simple and the info you need is encoded as plain text (ASCII). Once the device locks onto 3+ satellites, you'll get a position updates on a regular basis.

Comment: I would try that, but my GPS can't get a fix inside, so I can't read the text coming out. Do you have any other hints?